# My internet doesn't connect automatically on Ubuntu anymore

Tags: internet

A few days ago I installed Apache on my Ubuntu operating system.

- I wanted to make the server public.
- Somehow I messed up the settings of the automatic internet connection at start-up.
- My printer can't be found anymore.
- I thought: OK I killed my Ubuntu account... then I will just create a new one and be more careful from now on ... no chance ..  there is also no internet.
- **Should I reinstall Ubuntu?**
- Now I have always to do at start-up manually to be connected to the internet.
  (**update** I only did `dhclient  -v` after reboot)

```bash
sudo dhclient -v

# and at first I also used the following cmd, but dhclient seems to be enough.

sudo ufw enable
```

**So if nothing works, could I just switch to another account?**

---

**What I tried**

- I didn't try much for not messing up that much
- I disabled ufw after enable and the internet still works (not surprising).

**Firewall  UFW status**

```
    sudo ufw status verbose
    Status: Aktiv
Protokollierung: on (low)
Voreinstellung: allow (eingehend), allow (abgehend), deny (gesendet)
Neue Profile: skip

Zu                         Aktion      Von
--                         ------      ---
80,443/tcp (Apache Full)   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
137,138/udp (Samba)        ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
139,445/tcp (Samba)        ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
5050                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
67,68/udp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
69/udp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80,443/tcp (Apache Full (v6)) ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
137,138/udp (Samba (v6))   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
139,445/tcp (Samba (v6))   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
5050 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
67,68/udp (v6)             ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
69/udp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             

67,68/udp                  ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
69/udp                     ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
67,68/udp (v6)             ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)             
69/udp (v6)                ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
```

**Ubuntu Version**

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.10
Release:    22.10
Codename:   kinetic
```

Here you can see that on the Ubuntu GUI is no connection logo.

[image: no internet symbol]

**app list**

```
sudo ufw app list 
Verfügbare Anwendungen:
  Apache
  Apache Full
  Apache Secure
  CUPS
  Samba
```

**networkd.conf**

```bash
  GNU nano 6.4               /etc/systemd/networkd.conf                         
# the networkd.conf.d/ subdirectory. The latter is generally recommended.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file and all drop-ins.
#
# See networkd.conf(5) for details.

[Network]
#SpeedMeter=no
#SpeedMeterIntervalSec=10sec
#ManageForeignRoutingPolicyRules=yes
#ManageForeignRoutes=yes
#RouteTable=

[DHCPv4]
#DUIDType=vendor
#DUIDRawData=

[DHCPv6]
#DUIDType=vendor
#DUIDRawData=
```

**/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml**

```yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  dhcp4: true
  nameservers:
     addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

**ruleset**

```
sudo nft list ruleset
```

Here is a link to the output:
https://textdoc.co/KUmuSJRQFTgtPvqL

**ip tables**: https://justpaste.it/chb5k

```
$sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
LIBVIRT_FWX  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
LIBVIRT_FWI  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
LIBVIRT_FWO  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-track-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain LIBVIRT_FWI (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             localhost/24         ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain LIBVIRT_FWO (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  localhost/24         anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain LIBVIRT_FWX (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain LIBVIRT_INP (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:67

Chain LIBVIRT_OUT (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:68

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:netbios-ssn
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ufw-user-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-before-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:bootps dpt:bootpc
ufw-not-local  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251          udp dpt:mdns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
ufw-user-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-user-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Maybe there are settings in your Un Complicated Firewall that govern this and it's not an Ubuntu thang afterall.

Comment: yes but how to fix it?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify: Exactly which release and flavor of Ubuntu you are using. Ubuntu Desktop 16.04? Ubuntu Server 22.10? Ubuntu Core 18? Xubuntu 22.04? Something else? Troubleshooting for different releases has changed over time, so please take the time to be accurate. If you don't know how to determine your release and flavor of Ubuntu, then use the Search bar at the top of the page to learn how.

Comment: Need output of `sudo ufw status verbose` not just the ufw status, can't see the reject drop rules. Anyway, update your main post with that data, if you please. You can have a "drop all" rule on the on the incoming traffic policy, and when you do ufw enable right before the next command it will clear the existing rules allow dhclient to bind and then probably work. But it's still misconfigured, I'm guessing.... If it's working completely with `ufw disable` then it's definitely something like this. Once ufw is enabled it persists on boot, it doesn't need to be redone over and over.

Comment: Hi, I updated it. Now I try again to find the youtube link/ tutorial, with which I killed my confg.  It must be in my  chronik...  And I will check what you have written again.

Comment: We don't know what you did so it's hard to help you. But if you type `history` in the terminal it will return the last 2000 commands you've ran and that should help you understand what you did

Comment: I can only see 500.  And as far as I see it right I only see some old gcc commands  and some other commands.. but not that what hat to do with that.

Comment: From what I understand of your question, internet works when ufw is disabled but doesn't work when you enable ufw? Could be worth looking at the output of `sudo nft list ruleset` which will give you all details of your firewall (ufw is just a high level abstraction layer)

Comment: I am not sure about the  needed status of ufw. For example right now it is disabled. .. Now I enable it with "enable".  And Internet also works. So it looks like that the ufw doesn't be that important for this issue like dhclient is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow ports 68-69 for dhclient to work. If you connect with UFW off, DHCP addresses are assigned. If you enable it, they stay. But you DHCP won't work with ports 68-69 disabled.

You need to allow UDP from port 68 (client) to port 67 (server).

Comment: ok I allowed them with sudo ufw allow in 67,68,69/udp and sudo ufw allow out 67,68,69/udp   .... but I still cant find my printer .. and there is still no network symbol?